I need help exporting figma designs to android Studio, all plugins on YouTube are from old videos and are not there anymore
Figma to code export problems. Tried YouTube video and could only get my hands on export kit - lightning storm which i think has been taken down by figma. Do i have to connect android Studio with figma before i can access my designs?. Relay, DhiWise etc are they still effective.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
